# how to get parent Row Details

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

In My above plunker If I press `+` button I am getting Present row details through scope.$modelValue;

But here I want to get the parent row Details how can I get.
I have tried with `$nodeScope.$parentNodeScope` but Here I am not getting any data regarding parent row details.

```
$scope.addParentRow = function (scope){
           var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;//Here I am getting child rowDetails
           var x = scope.$nodeScope.$parentNodeScope;//expecting parent rowDetails
           console.log("the parent id is ",x.id);
           nodeData.items.push({
                id: nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.items.length,
                rowId: nodeData.rowId + '.' + (nodeData.items.length + 1),
                items: []
            });
}
```